# Помогите понять на каком тесте у меня неправильно, руками всевозможные варианты перебираю-всё работает как должно

Tags: c#, олимпиада

Яндекс контест https://contest.yandex.ru/yacup/contest/19036/problems/D/

D. Поиск ломающего коммита

**P.S. Опять же криво вставляется, вставлю картинкой, для данной задачи это полагаю не важно, копипастить с условий нечего**

[image: Условия]
[image: Условие2]

Вот мой код

```
using System;

namespace Yandex2020_D
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int upN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(upN==1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"! 1");
                return;
            }
            int  n= upN / 2 ;
            int downN = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.Out.Flush();
            while (true)
            {
               
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")
                    downN = n;
                else
                    upN = n;

                n = (downN + upN) / 2;
                if (upN - downN < 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"! {n + 1}");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(n);
                Console.Out.Flush();
            }
            

        }
    }
}
```

Собственно WA на первом тесте, не могу понять почему, где не так работает

Comment: Вы так все соревнование решить хотите? Это же не спортивно :)

Comment: @tym32167 Ну я же сам его решаю, потом когда не получается вопросы задаю ) Я реально просто не понимаю где проблема, раз 100 на разные варианты прогонял)
P.S. Еще насчёт одной задачи с создателями тестов воюю, у них написано при отправке проверяющая система  .Net core 3.1 , та-же, что и у меня, но вот библиотеку using system.text.json у них она не знает, хотя в документации Майкрософт однозначно говорится что она там есть, я уже без неё написал, с помощью Replace , дак он и на него ругается у них, якобы только char принимает)

Comment: У них возможно не .NET Core 3.1, а .NET Standard 2.1, там отсутствует `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: @aepot скорее всего так и есть, просто написано то у них другое. Вообще шарпы не уважают, для python, c++, java, go расписали какими библиотеки можно пользоваться, для шарпа нет)

Comment: Задача кстати - типичная игра угадайка. Только в школе мы писали загадывающий алгоритм, а здесь отгадывающий. Выглядит вроде нормально.

Comment: Кстати, почему вы не приняли ни один ответ из предыдущего вопроса?

Comment: @aepot Просто сложно выбрать, с одной стороны вы кучу полезных исправлений указали, с другой по итогу "наш" вариант слишком медленный все равно по итогу, вариант предложенный другим рабочий, максимальные времязатараты на тестах 0. 26 секунд, но он тупо с нуля написал, а я просил оптимизировать...